# When pedaling forward my bike suddenly disingages and goes limp

Tags: crankset

My Ridgeback Velocity bicycle suddenly disengages and goes limp and loose when pedalling forward, similar as if I'm pedalling backwards.

Comment: Has this happened multiple times?

Answer (score 5):

From your description it sounds like a [freehub](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html) failure, where the pawls of the ratchet in the rear gears are sticky or broken.  It's a replaceable part.  Any bicycle repair shop should be able to provide it.